# How can i style my searchview in android?

Tags: android, search, colors, searchview, underline

I have a SearchView and I have been trying to change it's underline color without success. I also want to make it look like this:

[image]

(just like a simple line), with the method below, it changes the whole background and it looks bad. I want to change only the underline color so the background remains transparent

Here's how I am trying to change my underline color:

```
int searchPlateId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null);

searchView.findViewById(searchPlateId).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_bluethinline);
```

Comment: closing my account immediately, this website is useless where nobody helps you